# Random() not generating new random numbers

Tags: c#, random

Any help or insight on this would be appreciated. Still kind of a noob with c#, so please bear with me. Here's my problem:

```
List<Vector2> vectorList = new List<Vector2>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Vector2 tempVector = new Vector2(i, i);
    vectorList.Add(tempVector);
}
```

This works fine, the output I get is 5 vectors with the following values: (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2).. and so on...

I need to get random positions, so i did myself a little function called RandomizePosition().

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Vector2 tempVector = RandomizePosition();
    vectorList.Add(tempVector);
}
```

The output i get from this is 5 vectors, containing all the same positions. I'm guessing there is a referencing problem, or the function get called only once or something. Weird thing is, if I go through each loop in debug mode, the output is what I would expect, 5 vectors with different X and Y values, so i guess the function isn't the problem. (or rather it probably is, but not the randomizing logic inside it).

Any ideas on why this is happening, and some insight on how to fix this? Can't you call a function from a loop? Or how can i make sure the function gets called on each iteration? Thanks!

Here's the RandomizePosition() function, if it can help:

```
private Vector2 RandomizePosition()
{
   Random rand = new Random();

   int seedX = rand.Next(1, 14);
   int seedY = rand.Next(1, 14);

   int posX = 32;
   int posY = 32;

   if (seedX != 1)
       posX += seedX * 64;

   if (seedY != 1)
       posY += seedY * 64;

   return new Vector2(posX, posY);
}
```

Comment: upload your full code.............

Comment: Mitch is right: the reason you see "normal" behavior when you step through it is that you are causing enough time to elapse for your `new Random()` line to use a new seed (since it is based on the current time.) Without the step through, the loop runs fast enough that the time doens't change, and so neither does the seed.

Comment: I've uploaded the code, but i think i've got my answer already.. i'll try with the random object outside the method.. and yep it's working, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've rephrased your title to better reflect the actual question, which will also make it more relevant for anyone else who searches on a similar problem.

Comment: +1. You stuck around after asking the question, and added code and updated question when prompted. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Well, thank you for the quick answer... i feel like a total noob now, i was reading on loop closure and referencing and rocket science... basically way too far ahead.. or making it way more complicated than it was. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't feel like a noob: many people have been bitten by this at some point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown your `RandomizePosition()` method, but it is likely that you are calling randomise with the same time seed in quick succession, i.e. creating the `Random` object inside your  `RandomizePosition()` method.

To stop this happening create the `Random` object outside your `RandomizePosition()` method.

**Update**: you have now shown the code for `RandomizePosition()` and that is indeed the problem.

As mentioned by **@dlev**, the reason you see the expected behavior when you step through the code is that you are causing enough time to elapse for your newly created Random() object to use a new seed (since by default it is based on the current time) .

Answer (score 1):

you have declared the rand variable like this `Random rand = new Random();` which sholud not be done make the rand variable a static one and declare it in your class not in your method that time you will not be having such troubles

Comment: I mean 5 minutes after I answered.

Comment: Note that declaring `static Random` variables needs to be done with care: the class is not safe for multi-threaded usage, so access needs to be synchronized in those situations. (Though that is not likely the case for this particular question.)